# Extract a string with Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like:

```
ITEM 'SALES_ORDER_COMPANY'

ITEM 'SALES_ORDER_NUMBER'

ITEM 'SALES_ORDER_TYPE' 'SALES_ORDER_TYPE'

ITEM 'ORIGINATING_SYSTEM'

ITEM 'BATCH_DT' 'BATCH_DT'
CALCULATE 'some text here'

ITEM 'INVOICE_DT' 'INVOICE_DT'
CALCULATE 'some text here'
```

I want to extract Items followed by `CALCULATE` apart and the others Items apart.
for example :

```
extract 1 (ITEM 'BATCH_DT' 'BATCH_DT'
           CALCULATE 'some text here')
extract 2 (ITEM 'INVOICE_DT' 'INVOICE_DT'
           CALCULATE 'some text here')
extract3  (ITEM 'SALES_ORDER_COMPANY')
extract4  (ITEM 'SALES_ORDER_NUMBER') ...
```

My idea is to extract items folowed by calculate first and replace them with "" then extract the other items, so I used this pattern but it doesn't worked for me

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^ITEM\\s'.*?'^CALCULATE'.*?'", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Do you have any control over the generation of the data string you receive?

Comment: i receive data  from access table (each line is a row) then i pute them in a String

Comment: Unless I'm missing something your data seem to be delimited by double newline (\n\n), you don't even need complicated regex for this

Comment: @gerrytan that's why i used Pattern MULTILINE with anchor ^

Comment: Can't you just split the string by "\n" token?

Comment: split by \n will give me each line apart but in the case where Item is folwed by Calculate i want to capture both line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did it

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(^ITEM\\s.+?)^(?=ITEM|DATASOURCE)",Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```